# Stop image from overlapping when browser changes size

Tags: html, css

For a website I'm working on I have a video as my landing page that takes up the full page and right below is a photo, my problem is that when I change the viewport to a smaller width the image proceeds to overlap with the video blocking the view of the video.

HTML CODE

```
<header>
    <h1><a href="#cover">Head</a></h1>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about_us">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">OUR TEAM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sponsors">OUR SPONSERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </div>
</header>
<div id = "cover">
    <video autoplay="true" muted loop>
        <source src="Images/5032play.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
    <div class="coverText">
      <div id="topText">
        <span><h1>Welcome</h1></span><br>
        <span><h1>to</h1></span><br>
      </div>  
        <span><h1>The website</h1></span><br>
        <span><h1>lorem</h1></span>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="about_us">

    <div class="Intro">
        <img src="Images/TeamPhoto.jpg" alt="TeamPhoto">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>About Us</h1>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

CSS

```
div#cover {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 50%; }

div#cover video {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; }

div.coverText {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -270px;
  font-size: 30px; }

div#topText {
  font-size: 10px; }

div.coverText h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  text-align: center; }

section#about_us {
  padding: 25px 0; }

div.Intro {
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center; }

div.Intro div.content {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

div.Intro h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px; }

div.Intro p {
  max-width: 980px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 40px 0; }
```

IS there any way to stop this?
Thanks!

Comment: This code doesn't really replicate what you're describing

Comment: You need to use `media queries`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `max-width: 100%`?
https://codepen.io/Liveindream/pen/VwYXXyE